# How can I update the data inside a model with an action in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a model called 'demande', with a particular field named 'statut' with default value 'en cours'. I created an action where when the button is clicked the 'statut' field value becomes 'Validé'

demande.php(the model)

`protected[ 'type' 'statut' ]`

Validate.php(the action)
`

```
public function handle($model, View $mainValidator){
        $model->update([
            'statut' => 'Validé'
        ]);
    }
```

`
ValPcTableView.php(the livewire component where I implemented the action)

```
public function actionsByRow(){
    return[
        new Validate,
        new Refuse,
        new Consulter
    ];
}
```

It always return 'Call to a member function update() on array'

Comment: Can you show how you called that action?

Comment: Try with `$model->statut = 'Validé';  $model->save();`  if still error it means your Model has no item...

Comment: I implemented it inside the livewire component:

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of approaching this. If you already have a model here, you can simply add a parameter to it and then save it. But be sure to check if your model extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Your model would look something like this:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class demande extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['type', 'statut'];
}
```

Your model update would look like this:

```
$model->statut = 'Validé';
$model->save();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#updates